# How to get a full dataframe to show without pagebreak in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

How do I get the dataframe to show the full dataframe in the spyder console, not with a page break? My dataframe does have alot of columns, but I want to be able to scroll horizontally like in google colab [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8mT5.png)

I've included pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)  To display dataframe without line wrapping, and also display.max_columns and rows. Any other ideas? Or is this a spyder - console specific setting I need to change.

```
# main.py
from player import Player



def main():
    # Prompt user for input
    player_name = input("Enter player name: ")
    season = str(input("Enter season: "))
    
    # Create player object
    player = Player(player_name)

    # Fetch player data (game log, etc.)
    player.fetch_data(season)

    # Display fetched data
    print("Game Log:")
    print(player.game_log_log)
    

    # Display Season Stats
    print("Season Stats:")
    print(player.season_stats)
    
    print("Advanced Stats:")
    print(player.advanced_stats)
    
    # Test get matchups with team of player
    team_abbreviation = input("Enter team abbreviation: ")
    matchups_with_team = player.get_matchups_with_team(team_abbreviation, season)
    print("Matchups with Team:")
    print(matchups_with_team)

    # Test get matchups with team of team
    team_abbreviation_opponent = input("Enter opponent team abbreviation: ")
    matchups_with_opponent = player.get_matchups_with_team_of_team(team_abbreviation_opponent, season)
    print("Matchups with Opponent Team:")
    print(matchups_with_opponent)

    # Test get advanced stats for matchups
    advanced_stats_for_matchups = player.get_advanced_stats_for_matchups(matchups_with_team, player.player_id)
    print("Advanced Stats for Matchups:")
    for idx, stats_df in enumerate(advanced_stats_for_matchups):
        print(f"Game {idx+1}:")
        print(stats_df)
        print()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# player.py
from nba_api.stats.static import players 
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playergamelog
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playernextngames
from data_processing import get_season_advanced_stats_player, get_season_general_stats, get_matchups_with_team_of_player, get_matchups_with_team_of_team, get_advanced_stats_for_matchups
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # To display all columns
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)  # To display dataframe without line wrapping
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # To display all rows



class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.player_id = None
        self.team_id = None
        self.game_log = None
        self.season_stats = None
        self.advanced_stats = None
        self.matchups_with_team = None
        self.matchups_with_opponent = None
        self.advanced_stats_for_matchups = None

    def fetch_data(self, season):
        # Fetch player and team ID using NBA API
        self.player_id = self._fetch_player_info()
    
        # Fetch game log for the specified season using NBA API
        self.game_log = self._fetch_game_log(season)
        
        # Fetch season and advanced stats using data_processing module
        print("Fetching season stats...")
        self.season_stats = get_season_general_stats(self.player_id, season)
        print("Season stats:\n", self.season_stats)
        
        print("Fetching advanced stats...")
        self.advanced_stats = get_season_advanced_stats_player(self.player_id, season)
        print("Advanced stats:", self.advanced_stats)
        
        # Fetch matchups with a specific team
        team_abbreviation = input("Enter team abbreviation: ")
        print("Fetching matchups with team...")
        self.matchups_with_team = get_matchups_with_team_of_player(self.player_id, team_abbreviation, season, self.game_log)
        print("Matchups with Team:")
        print(self.matchups_with_team)
        
        # Fetch matchups with a specific opponent team
        opponent_team_abbreviation = input("Enter opponent team abbreviation: ")
        print("Fetching matchups with opponent team...")
        self.matchups_with_opponent = get_matchups_with_team_of_team(self.team_id, opponent_team_abbreviation, season, self.game_log)
        print("Matchups with Opponent Team:")
        print(self.matchups_with_opponent)
        
        # Fetch advanced stats for matchups
        print("Fetching advanced stats for matchups...")
        self.advanced_stats_for_matchups = get_advanced_stats_for_matchups(self.matchups_with_team, self.player_id)
        print("Advanced Stats for Matchups:")
        for idx, stats_df in enumerate(self.advanced_stats_for_matchups):
            print(f"Game {idx+1}:")
            print(stats_df)
            print()


    def _fetch_player_info(self):
        player_dict = players.get_active_players()
        player = [player for player in player_dict if player['full_name']  == self.name][0]
        player_id = player['id']
        return player_id
    
    def _fetch_game_log(self, season):
        gamelog = playergamelog.PlayerGameLog(player_id = self.player_id, season = season)
        gamelog_df = gamelog.get_data_frames()[0]
        return gamelog_df  

    def _fetch_team_id_from_nextgame(self):
        # Fetch NextGame dataset
        next_game = playernextngames.PlayerNextNGames(player_id=self.player_id, number_of_games=1)
        next_game_df = next_game.get_data_frames()[0]
        # Extract team ID from the NextGame dataset
        team_id = next_game_df['Player_Team_id'].iloc[0]
        return team_id

#data_processing 
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # To display all columns
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)  # To display dataframe without line wrapping
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # To display all rows
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playercareerstats
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playerdashboardbygeneralsplits
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import boxscoreadvancedv3
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playernextngames


def get_season_general_stats(player_id: int, season: str): 
    """
    get player season_stats
    
    returns panda dataframe
    
    """

    career_stats = playercareerstats.PlayerCareerStats(player_id, per_mode36='PerGame')
    career_stats_data = career_stats.get_data_frames()[0]
    season_stats = career_stats_data[career_stats_data['SEASON_ID'] == '2023-24']
    return season_stats


def get_season_advanced_stats_player(player_id: int, season: str): 
    """
    Advanced stats of the player
    
    Returns panda dataframe
    """
    
    advanced_stats = playerdashboardbygeneralsplits.PlayerDashboardByGeneralSplits(player_id, 
                                                                              season, 
                                                                              measure_type_detailed='Advanced', 
                                                                              per_mode_detailed='PerGame')
    advanced_stats_df = advanced_stats.get_data_frames()[0]
    selected_columns = ['W', 'L', 'NET_RATING', 'REB_PCT', 'AST_PCT', 'AST_TO', 'TM_TOV_PCT', 'E_TOV_PCT', 'EFG_PCT', 'TS_PCT', 'USG_PCT', 'E_USG_PCT', 'POSS', 'E_OFF_RATING_RANK', 'E_DEF_RATING_RANK', 'NET_RATING_RANK', 'AST_PCT_RANK', 'AST_TO_RANK', 'REB_PCT_RANK', 'TM_TOV_PCT_RANK', 'EFG_PCT_RANK', 'USG_PCT_RANK'] 
    advanced_stats_selected = advanced_stats_df[selected_columns]
    return advanced_stats_selected
    

def get_next_game_of_player(player_id: int, season: str) ->None: 
    """
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    player_id : int
        player's id.
    season : str
        season.

    Returns
    -------
    List
        Find's the next game of the player.

    """
    next_game = playernextngames.PlayerNextNGames(player_id, number_of_games= 1)
    next_game_df = next_game.get_data_frames()[0]
    return next_game_df


def get_matchups_with_team_of_player(player_id: int, team_abbreviation: str, season: str, gamelog_df):
    # Filter game log to include only matchups against the specified team
    matchups_df = gamelog_df[gamelog_df['MATCHUP'].str.contains(team_abbreviation)]
    return matchups_df

def get_matchups_with_team_of_team(team_id: int, team_abbreviation: str, season: str, gamelog_df):
    # Filter game log to include only matchups against the specified team
    teammatchups_df = gamelog_df[gamelog_df['MATCHUP'].str.contains(team_abbreviation)]
    return teammatchups_df


def get_advanced_stats_for_matchups(matchups_df, player_id) -> list:
    """
    Get advanced box score stats for the matchups.
    Returns a list of pandas dataframes containing advanced stats.
    """
    advanced_stats_list = []

    for game_id in matchups_df['GAME_ID']:
        # Retrieve box score for the game
        boxscore = boxscoreadvancedv3.BoxScoreAdvancedV3(game_id=game_id)
        boxscore_df = boxscore.player_stats.get_data_frame()

        # Filter box score to include only stats of the specified player
        player_stats = boxscore_df[boxscore_df['PLAYER_ID'] == player_id]

        # Append advanced stats of the player for the game to the list
        advanced_stats_list.append(player_stats)

    return advanced_stats_list
```

Comment: You can't with Spyder. Google colab, databricks, Jupyter, etc are notebooks that are built off html, which makes it possible for tabular data to be displayed in a scrollable way. I hear Pycharm does have capabilities to do it in the console. But as far as I know Spyder does not in the console. so you need to view in the variable viewer, or have the table open up in the browser as an html.